# Stacked bar chart : what if each subcategory (fill) is unique?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

**Context**
I have a data set where observations are described using categories and subcategories. Subcategories are such that a given one is linked to one category only (think "category ~ car brand" and "subcategory ~ car model").

Imagine I count the number of cars I can see passing each day through my window. I should get a data set similar to this:

```
 _______________________________________________________
| Date      | Brand         | Model         | Count     |
|===========:===============:===============:===========|
| 18-01-01  | Ford          | Model T       | 1         |
| 18-01-01  | Ford          | Focus         | 13        |
| 18-01-01  | Tesla         | Model X       | 17        |
| 18-01-02  | Ford          | Model T       | 1         |
| 18-01-02  | Honda         | Civic         | 210       |
| _         | _             | _             | _         |
|___________|_______________|_______________|___________|
```

**Problem**
I want to create a (horizontal) bar plot showing the count of entries grouped by category (i.e. each bar represents one brand). Moreover, I would like to have each bar graphically subdivided per model (i.e. the closest to axis part of a bar representing the most counted model of the brand, then the second-most counted model, etc.).

I can produce such graph, but each subcategory is then represented as a single legend item (see the first graph in the example below). But in my real example I have a dozen of categories — each of them using a dozen of subcategories (hence about 150 subcategories in total). This makes such solution not "usable".

[image]

**Question**
How to produce such a graph, where each bar (~brand) has one color (blue/red/yellow), and each subcategory a monochromatic shade/tint variation of it (dark blue/medium blue/light blue; dark red/…)?

 (Indeed, subcategories are car models, hence specific to each brand — and not a generic/multi-brand category such as "the most observed model of the brand". Moreover, the amount of model per brand varies.)

[image]

---

**Example**

I can produce a close result using following code (see data at the bottom of the example):

```
library(ggplot2)
df = read.csv('fake-data.csv', header = TRUE)
df <- df[order(df$car_brand, decreasing = FALSE),]
ggplot(df, aes(x=car_brand, y=count, fill = car_model)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip()
```

However, I get a single color and legend entry for each single model.
I would prefer one color per brand, with a variation in shade/tint of the given color for each model of the brand.

Here is the content of `fake-data.csv`, with obviously fake data:

```
month,car_brand,car_model,count
18-01,Tesla,Model X,8
18-01,Ford,Model T,11
18-01,Ford,Focus,9
18-01,Ford,Focus,19
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,8
18-01,BMW,1 series,4
18-01,Ford,Model T,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,13
18-01,Ford,Model T,9
18-01,Tesla,Model S,18
18-01,BMW,1 series,6
18-01,Ford,Focus,10
18-01,Honda,Civic,9
18-01,Audi,A6,14
18-01,Audi,R8,19
18-01,Ford,Focus,13
18-01,BMW,1 series,7
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,12
18-01,BMW,1 series,11
18-01,BMW,1 series,9
18-01,BMW,1 series,4
18-01,BMW,1 series,11
18-01,Ford,Model T,17
18-01,Honda,Civic,10
18-01,BMW,1 series,9
18-01,Ford,Focus,19
18-01,Honda,Civic,9
18-01,Ford,Focus,15
18-01,Audi,A8,12
18-01,Tesla,Model X,6
18-01,Honda,Civic,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,16
18-01,Tesla,Model X,18
18-01,Tesla,Model X,16
18-01,Audi,TT,20
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,9
18-01,Tesla,Model X,21
18-01,BMW,1 series,9
18-01,Audi,A8,18
18-01,BMW,1 series,2
18-01,Ford,Focus,2
18-01,Honda,Civic,7
18-01,Tesla,Model X,9
18-01,Honda,Civic,3
18-01,BMW,1 series,5
18-01,Ford,Focus,14
18-01,Honda,Civic,4
18-01,Tesla,Model S,4
18-01,Honda,Civic,7
18-01,Honda,Civic,13
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,3
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,9
18-01,BMW,1 series,13
18-01,Ford,Model T,11
18-01,Ford,Focus,10
18-01,Tesla,Model S,18
18-01,Audi,Q3,6
18-01,Audi,R8,13
18-01,Tesla,Model X,21
18-01,BMW,1 series,13
18-01,Ford,Focus,17
18-01,Tesla,Model X,14
18-01,Audi,TT,3
18-01,Ford,Model T,11
18-01,Honda,Civic,7
18-01,Ford,Focus,4
18-01,Honda,accord,6
18-01,Ford,Focus,10
18-01,Ford,Model T,10
18-01,Honda,Civic,15
18-01,Ford,Model T,2
18-01,Tesla,Model X,10
18-01,Ford,Focus,11
18-01,Tesla,Model X,14
18-01,Honda,Civic,13
18-01,BMW,1 series,19
18-01,BMW,1 series,21
18-01,Ford,Focus,8
18-01,Tesla,Model X,12
18-01,Honda,Civic,5
18-01,Honda,Civic,14
18-01,Honda,Civic,17
18-01,Audi,R8,16
18-01,Honda,Civic,12
18-01,Audi,A6,20
18-01,Tesla,Model X,4
18-01,Audi,TT,4
18-01,Ford,Focus,16
18-01,Audi,Q3,16
18-01,BMW,1 series,12
18-01,Audi,A8,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,1
18-01,Audi,A8,7
18-01,Audi,Q3,10
18-01,Tesla,Model X,18
18-01,Ford,Focus,19
18-01,Ford,Model T,2
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,15
18-01,Ford,Model T,13
18-01,Ford,Model T,2
18-01,Audi,Q3,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,4
18-01,Audi,R8,1
18-01,Honda,Civic,2
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,4
18-01,BMW,1 series,16
18-01,Audi,A8,5
18-01,Ford,Model T,18
18-01,Tesla,Model X,21
18-01,Ford,Focus,4
18-01,Ford,Focus,7
18-01,BMW,1 series,16
18-01,Tesla,Model X,16
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,8
18-01,BMW,1 series,13
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,7
18-01,Ford,Focus,21
18-01,BMW,1 series,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,10
18-01,Ford,Focus,11
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,13
18-01,Honda,Civic,4
18-01,Ford,Focus,11
18-01,Ford,Focus,8
18-01,BMW,1 series,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,15
18-01,Ford,Focus,9
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,4
18-01,BMW,1 series,5
18-01,Tesla,Model S,5
18-01,Audi,TT,12
18-01,Honda,Civic,17
18-01,BMW,1 series,9
18-01,Honda,Civic,7
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,15
18-01,Audi,A8,21
18-01,Ford,Model T,21
18-01,Ford,Model T,9
18-01,BMW,1 series,18
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,7
18-01,BMW,1 series,15
18-01,BMW,1 series,2
18-01,Ford,Model T,18
18-01,Audi,R8,17
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,3
18-01,Audi,A8,9
18-01,BMW,1 series,10
18-01,Audi,Q3,4
18-01,BMW,1 series,8
18-01,Honda,accord,19
18-01,Tesla,Model S,6
18-01,Audi,TT,18
18-01,Audi,Q3,21
18-01,Tesla,Model S,3
18-01,Tesla,Model S,9
18-01,Audi,Q3,1
18-01,Tesla,Model X,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,8
18-01,Audi,R8,14
18-01,Honda,Civic,21
18-01,Tesla,Model X,9
18-01,Audi,TT,16
18-01,Audi,A8,19
18-01,Ford,Focus,2
18-01,BMW,1 series,12
18-01,Ford,Model T,9
18-01,Tesla,Model X,9
18-01,Audi,R8,18
18-01,Honda,Civic,3
18-01,Honda,accord,7
18-01,Audi,A6,13
18-01,Audi,A8,13
18-01,Ford,Focus,8
18-01,Honda,accord,10
18-01,Audi,R8,20
18-01,Honda,Civic,18
18-01,Ford,Focus,7
18-01,Audi,R8,10
18-01,Audi,A6,13
18-01,Honda,Civic,4
18-01,Audi,A8,7
18-01,Audi,Q3,15
18-01,Honda,Civic,10
18-01,Audi,A8,6
18-01,Honda,Civic,1
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,21
18-01,Ford,Model T,7
18-01,BMW,1 series,6
18-01,Honda,Civic,4
18-01,Audi,A6,12
18-01,Honda,Civic,6
18-01,Tesla,Model S,17
18-01,Tesla,Model S,2
18-01,Tesla,Model X,6
18-01,Audi,A8,2
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,4
18-01,BMW,1 series,20
18-01,Honda,accord,17
18-01,Honda,Civic,14
18-01,BMW,1 series,16
18-01,Audi,A8,17
18-01,Audi,A6,11
18-01,Ford,Model T,1
18-01,BMW,1 series,18
18-01,Tesla,Model 3,11
18-01,Honda,Civic,21
```

Comment: You can map to `alpha`, but AFAIK there's no simple way to map to saturation currently. It's an interesting idea, though.

Comment: This is currently not possible in vanilla `ggplot`. See e.g. hadley's reply in the closed issue [Allow several simultaneous colour scales](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/578). On the other hand, if you google "ggplot multiple color scales" you will find various work-arounds.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but this has a few approaches that are similar to @Melissa Key's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50163072/5325862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to map to `alpha` - it's the closest thing I know of to get what you are after.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(car_brand, car_model) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(count), sum) %>%
  group_by(car_brand) %>%
  mutate(
    model_rank = car_model %>% rank(),
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = car_brand, y = count, fill = car_brand, alpha = model_rank)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(1, .25)) + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') + 
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that is honestly more complicated than it needs to be. In most situations I'd just recommend @Melissa Key's answer with mapping to alpha, but I got curious about ways to do this that might scale. This makes use of pasting multiple color palettes together, one for each make, and assigning names to each item in this vector based on make.

The first thing I did was summarize the data frame for total counts by make and model. Then I made both make and model into factors, and ordered them using `forcats` functions to rank by make (just left it alphabetical, but you could change this), and then by most common model.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

df_sums <- df %>%
  group_by(car_brand, car_model) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(car_brand = as.factor(car_brand)) %>%
  mutate(car_model = as.factor(car_model) %>% fct_reorder2(car_brand, count, .desc = T)) %>%
  arrange(car_brand, car_model)

df_sums
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#>    car_brand car_model count
#>    <fct>     <fct>     <int>
#>  1 Audi      A8          154
#>  2 Audi      R8          128
#>  3 Audi      Q3           87
#>  4 Audi      A6           83
#>  5 Audi      TT           73
#>  6 BMW       1 series    413
#>  7 Ford      Focus       284
#>  8 Ford      Model T     189
#>  9 Honda     Civic       346
#> 10 Honda     accord       59
#> 11 Tesla     Model X     250
#> 12 Tesla     Model 3     169
#> 13 Tesla     Model S      82
```

From that, I mapped along a split version of the data frame and a vector of palette names, so I could get Color Brewer palettes by name, one for each make. The single hue sequential scales are a good fit for this and are convenient to fetch. The problem here is that you need to give the number of colors in `brewer.pal`, but this returns a minimum of 3 colors, so you need to subset the vector of colors to just give the right number of colors. This wouldn't be necessary in a situation where you have more colors per palette, or using something other than `brewer.pal` to get palettes. Then I set the names of the colors palettes to the names of the models, to keep things in order in the `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
pals <- c("Blues", "Purples", "Greens", "Reds", "Oranges")

colors <- df_sums %>%
  split(.$car_brand) %>%
  map2(pals, function(d, pal) {
    n <- nrow(d)
    brewer.pal(n, pal)[1:n] %>%
      setNames(d$car_model)
  }) %>%
  reduce(c)

head(colors)
#>        A8        R8        Q3        A6        TT  1 series 
#> "#EFF3FF" "#BDD7E7" "#6BAED6" "#3182BD" "#08519C" "#EFEDF5"

df_sums %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = car_brand, y = count, fill = car_model)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

[image]

I haven't figured out why the legend comes out in this order, but you could either change the order of the labels, or forgo the legend altogether, depending on you desired output. Hopefully that wasn't too convoluted!