# Is there a ggplot function for coloring subgroups in stacked bar-charts in different gradients?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I have counts of species and different samples, and the species belong to a specific group. 
What I would like to show is a plot, where the different species are colored by their group. So each species has it's own color, but in different shades according to the group they belong to. Eg. all bacteria in shades of grey, all trees in shades of green, all algae in shades of blue.
Ideally also the legend would be grouped by these groups.

This is how my data is structured:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyverse")

mydata <- data.frame(counts=c(560,  310,    250,    243,    124,    306,    1271,   112, 201, 305, 201, 304, 136, 211, 131 ), 
           species=c("bact1",   "bact1",    "shrub1",   "shrub1",   "tree1",    "tree1",    "tree2",    "algae1", "algae1", "bact2", "bact3", "tree3", "algae2", "shrub2", "shrub2"),
           sample=c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2),
           group=c("bacterium", "bacterium", "shrub", "shrub", "tree", "tree", "tree", "algae", "algae", "bacterium", "bacterium", "tree", "algae", "shrub", "shrub"))
```

```r
> mydata
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   counts species sample group    
    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <fct>    
 1    560 bact1        1 bacterium
 2    310 bact1        2 bacterium
 3    250 a-tree1      1 tree     
 4    243 c-tree2      1 tree     
 5    124 c-tree1      2 tree     
 6    306 a-tree1      2 tree     
 7   1271 tree2        1 tree     
 8    112 algae1       1 algae    
 9    201 algae1       2 algae    
10    305 bact2        2 bacterium
11    201 bact3        2 bacterium
12    304 tree3        2 tree     
13    136 algae2       1 algae    
14    211 tree2        1 tree     
15    131 tree2        2 tree
```

I already got nice looking stacked bar-charts, however the colors are given just in the order of the labels, which is alphabetically (To show this I named some of them a- and c-tree).

This is the basic plot:

```r
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=sample, y=counts, fill=species))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
  labs(x = "Samples", y = "Percentage of reads", fill = "Classification") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
plot
```

[image: plot]

So I tried many different things of what I found on stack overflow, but couldn't get it to work.
The most promising way, I thought, is to put in a factor like:

```r
mydata$group <- as.factor(mydata$group)
```

and then adding to the plot a subgroup:

```r
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=sample, y=counts, fill=species, subgroup=group))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
  labs(x = "Samples", y = "Percentage of reads", fill = "Classification") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

But this doesn't change a thing. And this would be only the first step to then give the groups a color.

One of the problems, why most of the answers given on stack overflow is that I have a lot of data, and there is not each species in every sample present. So I can't just give every single species a color. Although I was already so desperate that I tried that too but it wouldn't work for some reason, and anyway it would not be a neat way to do it...

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 2

Here is an approach using hcl.colors that can also handle factors not in alphabetical order. Further, I use forcats::fct_relevel, so that the species are printed in the order of color shades not a-z, see [Factors with forcats Cheat Sheet](https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-developed/factors)

```r
set.seed(1)
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyverse")
mydata <- data_frame(counts=c(560,  310,    250,    243,    124,    306,    1271,   112, 201, 305, 201, 304, 136, 211, 131 ), 
                     species=c("zbact1",   "bact1",    "shrub1",   "shrub1",   "tree1",    "tree1",    "tree2",    "algae1", "algae1", "bact2", "bact3", "tree3", "algae2", "shrub2", "shrub2"),
                     sample=c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2),
                     group=c("bacterium", "bacterium", "shrub", "shrub", "tree", "tree", "tree", "algae", "algae", "bacterium", "bacterium", "tree", "algae", "shrub", "shrub"))
#> Warning: `data_frame()` is deprecated, use `tibble()`.
#> This warning is displayed once per session.
mydata$species <- as.factor(mydata$species)
mydata$group <- as.factor(mydata$group)

make_pal <- function(group, sub){
  stopifnot(
    is.factor(group),
    is.factor(sub)
  )
  # all the monochromatic pals in RColorBrewer
  mono_pals <- c("Blues", "Greens", "Oranges", "Purples", "Reds", "Grays")
  # how many sub levels per group level
  data <- tibble(group = group, sub = sub) %>% 
    distinct()  
  d_count <- data %>% 
    count(group) 
  names_vec <- data %>% 
    arrange(group) %>% 
    magrittr::extract("sub") %>% 
    unlist
  # make a named vector to be used with scale_fill_manual
  l <- list(
    n = d_count[["n"]],
    name = mono_pals[1:length(levels(group))]
  )
  map2(l$n,
       l$name,
       hcl.colors) %>% 
    flatten_chr() %>% 
    set_names(names_vec)
} 

custom_pal <- make_pal(mydata$group, mydata$species)
mydata$species <- fct_relevel(mydata$species, names(custom_pal))
myplot <- mydata %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=sample, y=counts, fill=species))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
  labs(x = "Samples", y = "Percentage of reads", fill = "Classification") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_pal)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
myplot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! Now I see, why I just couldn't manage it by  my own, trying to learn R by doing, for two weeks now - it is quite a complex thing! So thank you again for setting this up for me! Now there is just a tiny little problem left, and this is, that I have more values, than there are colors in the monochromatic palettes (there are 10 and I need 37)... I found already out, that there is the function colorRampPalette, but as the code is so complex, I can't see how and where to add this... Could you help me another time here?

Comment: the problem is that what you want is not "good" plotting, by the definitions of ggplot. so workarounds are always cumbersome. I suggest you look at ggplot2 book by hadley, to get an idea of the theory behind the package.  if you want to use a different function to generate the palettes, try swapping  `mono_pals <- c("Blues", "Greens", "Oranges", "Purples", "Reds", "Greys")` and
  `pal <- function(n, name) RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, name)[1:n]` that is the part that generates the scales.

Comment: I have updated it with `hcl.colors()` that takes more species.. If you want to swap the palettes, you can display the available names with `hcl.pals()`

Comment: Hi @Bernd, thanks for the update! I now spend quite some time with the code. It works fine, when I exchanged "Greys" for "Grays" and added some extra color palettes for the number of groups I have. However, the only thing is, and that was one of the problems I had from the beginning, that somehow the code orders everything alphabetically. So it counts the number of occurences of every group and then assigns the colors to the alphabetic order of species.... It doesn't show up in the example, as there everything is by chance alphabetical.

Comment: so i have changed it now to work with non alphabetical lists :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest way but I used a workaround inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163072/different-colors-with-gradient-for-subgroups-on-a-treemap-ggplot2-r#50163458). I mapped the `fill` aesthethic to the `group` and `alpha` to `species`. Then I needed to add a white background to make it look nicer. Finally changed the range of alpha to restrict the minimum value of it.

Here is the result.

```
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=sample, y=counts, fill=group, alpha=species))+
   geom_bar(fill = "white",alpha = 1, stat="identity", position = "fill") +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
   labs(x = "Samples", y = "Percentage of reads", fill = "Classification") +
   theme(legend.position="bottom") +
   scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.3, 1)) 
myplot
```

And the result looks like this:
[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks very much ofr this quick reply, it looks already quite as I pictured it! I had read the page you linked as well, but never managed to apply it to my data, thank you!! However, it is impossible form the legend to tell, which color in the plot belongs to which species. So one would need to somehow find a way of overlaying the legend label colors as well... Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I am glad. I also tried to the merge by setting the same name for the labels but I didn't succeed. I assumed since there are lot of species, you don't want to do it. Alternatively I can suggest to add text on each part of the bar. Btw ignore the edit I proposed in the question. As I forgot to load tidyverse, the code didn't worked for me at first.